# Mongoose Post with Mixed/Geospatial Schemas

Tags: express, mongoose

Hello i'm using Mongoose and Express to submit geospatial data for a map (GEOJSON).
I have a form which gets the longitude and latitude for a point and the user can then submit to save this point.

My form works if I hard code the values in the 'coordinates' part of my post route, but if I try to do req.body.longitude and req.body.latitude it doesnt post to the array and gets me a 'req not defined' error.

I picked up the basics of mongoose geojson here:
https://gist.github.com/aheckmann/5241574

How can I make this form save from req.body values in a mixed schema? Thanks.

**My Schema**

```
var schema = new Schema({
  type: {type: String},
  properties: {
    popupContent: {type: String}
  },
  geometry: {
      type: { type: String }
    , coordinates: {}
  }
});
schema.index({ geometry: '2dsphere' });
var A = mongoose.model('A', schema);
```

**My Post Route**

```
    app.post('/api/map', function( request, response ) {
      console.log("Posting a Marker");
        var sticker = new A({
        type: 'Feature',
        properties: {
          popupContent: 'compa'
        },
    geometry: {
      type: 'Point',
      coordinates: [req.body.longitude, req.body.latitude]
    }
  });

sticker.save();
  return response.send( sticker );
  res.redirect('/map')
   });
```

**My Clientside Form**

```
 form(method='post', action='/api/map') 
  input#popup(type="text", value="click a button", name="popup")
  input#lng(type="text", value="click a button", name="longtude")
  input#lat(type="text", value="click a button", name="latitude")
  input(type="submit")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function signature states that there is no `req` parameter.

```
 app.post('/api/map', function( request, response )
```

You should either rename your parameters in your signature or in the body.

```
app.post('/api/map', function(request, response) {
  console.log("Posting a Marker");
  var sticker = new A({
    type: 'Feature',
    properties: {
      popupContent: 'compa'
    },
    geometry: {
      type: 'Point',
      coordinates: [request.body.longitude, request.body.latitude]
    }
  });

  sticker.save();
  return response.send(sticker);
});
```

Uh, just seen this thread is dusty. Well…